# Find Formatted address by IP address using Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, maxmind, keycloak-gatekeeper

## Description

I'm using Keycloak and I need to send E-Mail to users whenever their login fails, about the failure. Per default, these email does contain an IP Address.

## Problematic

I need to include the formatted address comming from this IP address, but I don't know the SPI to use to re-implement emails.

## Idea

I've come across [this plugin from maxmind](https://maxmind.github.io/GeoIP2-java/) which can be used to implement a Keycloak SPI.

Comment: Why do you need the IP address here?

Keycloak provides an EmailProvider SPI already and you can extend that. Or you can make your own. 

Regardless, don't know why you need an IP address. Sending email, if you have an email provider, should work without that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've come across EmailProvider already. The IP Address is already there and I want to map the IP address to the location using maxmind.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I found this [FreeMarkerEmailTemplateProvider](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/email/freemarker/FreeMarkerEmailTemplateProvider.java) and I've just extended it.